# Slow opening of files in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file

Currently, I'm writing program which needs to load over 13K "*.json" files of different sizes from few lines to 100K lines.
Reading looks like:

```
[read_one_JSON(p) for p in filenames]

def read_one_JSON(path: str):
    with open(path, encoding='utf-8') as fh:
        data = json.load(fh)
        return File(data["_File__name"], data['_File__statements'], data['_File__matches'])
```

I load file, pass it into class File and read another file. Currently it takes about 2 minutes 20 seconds.
I found out, that when I remove processing of the data into class and make just:

```
[read_one_JSON(p) for p in filenames]

def read_one_JSON(path: str):
    with open(path, encoding='utf-8') as fh:
        data = json.load(fh)
```

It reduces time just by 10 seconds to 2 minutes and 10 seconds. So, then I removed also json.load to see what causes the time of reading. So, when leaving just:

```
[read_one_JSON(p) for p in filenames]

def read_one_JSON(path: str):
    with open(path, encoding='utf-8') as fh:
```

and not reading the data it still lasts 1 minute 45 seconds. It means, the opening of the files is slow. **Is there any way to speed up the opening part of the process, without putting everything into one file or parallelization?** It is an option, but I would like to know if there is something else to do about that.

Before, I realised such bottle neck I tried libraries like *ujson*, *orjson*, *msgspec*, but since the opening phase is slow, it made just small differences.

Comment: This could be good case for `multiprocessing`. Why no parallelization?

Comment: It is and I'm applying ```multiprocessing``` in another part of the programme. Right now I'm just wondering whether there exists something else I haven't heard of yet, probably not, since I couldn't find anything about it. If there doesn't anything else I will use multiprocessing (probably even when I'll find out other solution), I'm CS student, so every new knowledge is valuable.

Comment: Look into exactly which operation is slow -- if it's a filesystem issue, f/e, it should be addressed at the filesystem level, not by changing your Python code at all.

Comment: 13K files in 105 seconds equates to about 0.008 seconds per file. One ten thousandth of a second doesn't seem particularly slow.

Comment: If you want a tool that can do low-overhead tracing for the relevant analysis, I strongly recommend sysdig; it has built in "chisels" -- Lua scripts capable of doing various kinds of analysis, including identifying high-latency operations.

Comment: By the way -- depending on the details of the kinds of analysis you're doing, you might think of switching from a collection of separate files to an indexed database. There are document stores well-optimized for querying large collections of documents with similar structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating 13000 files in the current directory :

```py
import json

from tqdm import tqdm  # pip install tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(13_000)):
    filename = f"data_{i}.json"
    data = {"filename": filename}
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        json.dump(data, file)
```

```
100%|██████████| 13000/13000 [00:01<00:00, 8183.74it/s]
```

Which means it ran for less than 2 seconds on my computer. [`tqdm`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#readme) is just a very simple way to see throughput.
The script produced files like :

```json
{"filename": "data_0.json"}
```

Then reading them :

```py
import json

from tqdm import tqdm  # pip install tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(13_000)):
    filename = f"data_{i}.json"
    with open(filename, "rt") as file:
        data = json.load(file)
print(data)
```

```
100%|██████████| 13000/13000 [00:00<00:00, 16472.00it/s]
{'filename': 'data_12999.json'}
```

Which means that they were all read in less than one second.

Maybe it comes from the size of the files you read. If you have many large files, indeed it will take more time. But your disk does not seem like the only cause for the slowness.